# nuxt 3 I18n multiple domains

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, vue-i18n

i am trying to set different domains for my nuxt 3 app. But when i deploy it on server everytime i visit the url it returns

**404 Page not found: /sl**

but strategy in i18n is set to prefix. (if i disable different domains each domain works fine and has a prefix).

my nuxt.config.ts:

```
...
i18n: {
    strategy: 'prefix',
    locales: [
        {
            code: 'sl',
            name: 'Slovenščina',
            domain: process.env.SU_APP_URL,
            file: 'default.json',
        },
        {
            code: 'en',
            name: 'English',
            domain: process.env.CORNER_APP_URL,
            file: 'cen.json',
        },
    ],
    defaultLocale: 'sl',
    lazy: true,
    langDir: 'lang/',
    differentDomains: true,
    detectBrowserLanguage: false
},
```

any idea why its not working?